# Php form not sending input to the database and not showing print_r

Tags: php, mysql

So i have this code which is supposed to send name and email address to the database. Not only is it not doing that, but in my second line of code where I want it to print_r whatever has been entered I still get a blank screen. Is there a setting to show what errors are occurring in my code that I've got turned off or is this code wrong?

```
//Only process the form if $_POST isn't empty
if(! empty($_POST)){
    print_r($_POST); exit;


//Connect to MYSQL
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root','','snippets');

//Check connection
    if($mysqli ->connect_error){
        die('Connect Error: '. $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

//Insert data
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user(name, email) VALUES ('{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name'])}','{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])}' )";
    $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);

//Print reponse from MySQL
    if($insert){
        echo "Success! Row ID: {$mysqli->insert_id}";
    }else{
        die("Error: {$mysqli->errno}:{$mysqli->error}");
    }

//Close connection
    $mysqli ->close();
}
?>
<form method="post" action="">
    <input name="name" type="text">
    <input name="email" type="email">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
</form>
```

Comment: Please print_r before empty check function and comment the output

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still new how do I do that?

Comment: Google `error_reporting`

Comment: Just cut this "print_r($_POST); exit;" and paste before if statement

Comment: The result was Array() *edit. Actually it's still coming up as blank.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST` is not being populated on POST requests. The most likely cause is that your PHP is set to not create the superglobals (`$_POST`, `$_GET`...).

The fix may be in your `php.ini` file. Open that file and look for the setting `variables_order` ([See the docs](http://php.net/variables-order)).  I suspect that this has been commented out (or doesn't exist) in your configuration file.  Set it to:

```
variables_order = "EGPCS"
```

If you're not sure where the active `php.ini` is located, change your PHP file to have just the code below:

```
<?php
phpinfo(); exit;
```

A lot of info about your installation will appear. The value of `Loaded Configuration File` will tell you which file to edit to change your PHP settings.

**If all else fails**, you can extract the submitted values yourself; it's really simple:

```
$args = []; //will hold the submitted arguments
parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'),$args);
```

From there, just use `$args` as you would use `$_POST`. It contains your form inputs. Just be aware that it would also contain the inputs that you'd typically see in `$_GET`, when a "GET" request is made

Comment: I just tried that but it doesn't work, the page refreshes and I still get a blank page and nothing get's added to the database. I'm starting to wonder whether there is something wrong with my setup here. Could someone try and run this on their own machine and see if it's giving them a blank screen aswell please?

Comment: what do you see if you put `echo file_get_contents(file_get_contents('php://input');` at the top of the script?

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\wamp64\www\process.php on line 9 EDIT* just tried to submit this after filling the form and got Warning: file_get_contents(name=test&email=TEST%40EMAIL.COM): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\process.php on line 9

Comment: that's my fault. I used the function inside itself by mistake.  I meant `echo file_get_contents('php://input')`

Comment: When I enter some data and submit I now get :name=test&email=TEST%40EMAIL.COM

Comment: but `$_POST` is still empty??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117478/discussion-between-shady-and-beetlejuice).

Comment: Did `variables_order` setting fix it, or did you have to parse `php://input` yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there was a conflict between my WAMP server and the built-in server provided by Phpstorm which is the IDE I am using. as @Beetlejuice suspected there was also an issue in my php.ini file. This should have been uncomented and set to On: ;enable_post_data_reading = Off

Thank you to everyone who helped.

Answer (score -1):

> "INSERT INTO user(name, email) VALUES ('{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name'])}','{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])}' )"

Try using a backslash for "name" and "email" attributes. This will reduce ambiguity in quotes. Most of the time, that is the issue.

So, it would look like this:

```
"INSERT INTO user(name, email) VALUES ('{$mysqli-
>real_escape_string($_POST[\'name\'])}','{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST[\'email\'])}' )"
```

However, I think it would be best practice use "real_escape_string" before this query. Generally, the php is not run when used in a query string. So, save

$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name'] in one variable **AND**

$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'] in another variable **and then,**

add it to the query

Comment: My IDE is telling me that that code is wrong and I get a parsing error when I try to run it.

Comment: Although you're trying to help this is just making a mess of an already bad situation. The solution is prepared statements with placeholder values.